# Create Thumbnail while uploading video to CDN using Amazon transcoder

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I need to create a thumbnail from video while uploading it to CDN.

I also came across term [Amazon transcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624144/retrieve-file-and-thumbnail-url-from-aws-elastic-transcoder-job) but this is in ruby, I am using php, Is there way to do this in php.

I am using jwplayer for [playing video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887917/show-jwplayer-preview-image-from-video-without-image)

Can someone help me to create thumbnail while uploading video to CDN using amazon transcoder

Answer (score 0):

Use the official [PHP SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/) that Amazon provides. It fully supports the transcoder as well as all other Amazon services. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-elastictranscoder.html