# Getting error: Hostname not known: elastictranscoder.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, transcoding

I'm trying to transcode the video using aws elastic transcoder but I'm getting a SocketError. I Followed the steps followed in this question: [Retrieve file and thumbnail url from AWS Elastic Transcoder job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624144/retrieve-file-and-thumbnail-url-from-aws-elastic-transcoder-job). Please do look into the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sa-east-1` in your hostname indicates that your target region is São Paulo.

As of now, Elastic Transcoder is not deployed in that AWS region.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#elastictranscoder_region